# Mapping modules to packages

Tags: python, pip

How do I canonically determine/find/identify, without having the package installed, which package(s) a given module belongs to (so I can install it)?

I have a legacy code base. It has lots of `import` statements. If I want to install the referenced modules, say to populate `setup.py`, I need to know the package names, but there is no necessary relationship between the name of the module and the name of the package. For example, an `import cv2` is satisfied by the package `opencv-python`, not `cv2`. I'm left with googling, which is less than a satisfying solution.

It seems like this would be a common problem with a well-defined answer, but darned if I can find it. I found an answer that assumes the package is installed, but I want an answer if the package is not installed.

Comment: You have answered your own question: `there is no necessary relationship between the name of the module and the name of the package`. How could there be a solution to this (frustrating) problem, if there is no defined relationship between import an PyPi module name

Comment: @TYZ Yes, I think `pipreqs` is what I'm looking for. If you want to make it an answer, I'll make it accepted. For some reason it comes up with `opencv_python` instead of `opencv-python`, but they appear to be synonymous.

Comment: @FlyingTeller By "no defined relationship" I don't mean there isn't a relationship, I mean there is no rule that expresses the relationship such that it is predictable. I.e., while `cv2` maps to `opencv-python` (there is a relationship), nothing in the name `cv2` tells you to look for the package named `opencv-python` (there is no defined relationship). The relationship exists; it's just hidden in the Pypi repository.